# How can I make PhpStorm watch files (track Git ) that are mounted externally as a mapped drive

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a windows 10 Professional and I am mapping a remote drive from inside my VM.

I keep getting  this notification message `External file changes sync may be slow: Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount ?)`

Im assuming because of this reason, git file tracking is way off. Normally whenever I make file changes under git tracking, the filename turns blue, and new files are red and committed files are green. However after this mount, even though the files are already committed and pushed, PhpStorm still shows the file as blue and it is not syncing properly.

Other posts suggested mapping the network drive as a local disk. I have done that already, the mapped drive also has its own drive letter `"Y:/"`

Not sure which configuration I missed.

Comment: I'm struggling at this too.. Please answer your own question if you found something..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` and File Watcher Plugin in PHPStorm to achieve this.
You need to have MingW or WSL installed on your Windows Machine.

1. Create a `mage-sync.bat` file with below contents:

   ```
   REM Starting sync...
   bash -c "rsync -a /mnt/c/git/magento2/app/ hash:code/magento2/app/ --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --cvs-exclude"
   REM Finished syncing
   ```
2. Configure File Watcher Plugin as below:
   [image]

I have written a post on this [here](https://medium.com/fotonicia/sync-files-to-remote-server-with-phpstorm-on-windows-659b4c9a6bb).